# How to start Edge by calling C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe from cmd?

Tags: cmd.exe, microsoft-edge

Normally, running `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe` from cmd would start Edge, but since last windows update, the command is executed successfully, but Edge is not started.

Comment: Two weeks ago it worked

Comment: How about `start "" microsoft-edge:` or `start "" microsoft-edge:<URL>`? It seems [`explorer shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge`](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7755-create-shortcut-microsoft-edge-windows-10-a.html) does the trick too.

Comment: Is running it via `MicrosoftEdge.exe` a requirement or perhaps could you  use the method per the above comment I wrote?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Yeah at the moment it is a requirement, but if there is no solution, the build script has to be changed

Answer (score 1):

How about  -
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
(from the shortcut icon properties)

Answer (score 0):

As you've already figured out, Edge is a "protocol activated" application, so it does not load like a normal app from an EXE file.  Most of the time, this is not a problem as you can use the other techniques described in the comments above.

However, if you absolutely need to start Edge via an EXE file, then you can download a (very small) app that will do precisely that.

Take a look at this article to see if this is something that you'd be interested in:  http://www.edgemanage.emmet-gray.com/Articles/EdgeLaunch.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess the earlier version which you were on was the win32 app and in recent updates, they have moved it to UWP.

therefore the  `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe` won't work with UWP apps.

You have to use `explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\PackageFamilyName!Application ID`